# “No X11 DISPLAY variable” - what does it mean?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, jmeter, mesos, jmeter-plugins

I installed Jmeter on one of my Mesos nodes, but I can not run it I have this error that appears

```
================================================== ==============================
Do not use GUI mode for load testing, only for Test creation and Test debugging.
For load testing, use CLI Mode (was NOT GUI):
   jmeter -n -t [jmx file] -l [results file] -e -o [Path to web report folder]
& increase Java Heap to meet your test requirements:
   Modify current env variable HEAP = "- Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX: MaxMetaspaceSize = 256m" in the jmeter batch file
Check: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html
================================================== ==============================
An error occurred: Can not connect to the window server using ': 0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

Comment: Hi, I got this link which have explain similar issue:-http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21654543     .Check if this helps.

Comment: hello, thank you for your help, yes I already tried but without any result the problem is that my machine goes through a proxy before accessing the cluster node

Comment: An error occurred: Can't connect to X11 window server using '10.8.0.84:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DISPLAY` is only needed if you're running this in GUI mode.  Since you're running this in Mesos, you **cannot** use GUI mode.  Add the `-n` option to run in CLI mode.

[JMeter: Getting Started: CLI Mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)